# Connect to third party API with HTTParty post and get, Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, httparty

I am trying to connect to some API using HTTParty. First I need to login with my credentials to get the token and later I need to use this token for making other get requests.

When I do:

```
def get_token
    HTTParty.post(base_url + '/login', headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, body: body_hash).body
end
```

where

```
def body_hash
    {
        "username": "my_username",
        "apikey": "7867868yiuhi76"
    }.to_json
end
```

and with that I receive the token correctly.

Then I try to do GET to a different url on the API like this:

```
response = JSON.parse(get_token)            
data = HTTParty.get(base_url + '/some_path', headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization: Bearer" => response['token'] }).body
puts data
```

and I get error:

```
"Internal server error"
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue here? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide more information about the API you are using?

Comment: try headers as `{ "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer " +  response['token'] }`

Comment: @Anthony Changing headers in this way worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just have the parameters mixed up on the headers.  Assuming this is Oauth/Oauth2 you need to send over the 'Authorization' key with a value of 'Bearer token'.

So for your example:

```
HTTParty.get(base_url + '/some_path', headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer #{response['token']}" }).body
```